# Alfresco login issue after upgrade

Tags: tomcat, upgrade, alfresco

I'm upgrading alfresco, and when I try to log in to the new version, I get the following exception:

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
    at       com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.executeMethod(AbstractHttpClient.java:133)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.sendRemoteRequest(AbstractHttpClient.java:85)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.HttpClientFactory$HttpsClient.sendRequest(HttpClientFactory.java:307)
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:982)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackModels(CoreTracker.java:1405)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackRepository(CoreTracker.java:1127)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.updateIndex(CoreTracker.java:481)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTrackerJob.execute(CoreTrackerJob.java:45)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Could do you attach your starting logs please ? In catalina.out by default; From the moment you started Tomcat to the moment where Catalina is started. 
I think some errors happened during starting.